# Laravel make header

Tags: php, laravel, rss

How can I add a header to a response view in Laravel?

I tried this:

```
return View::make('rss', $data)->header('Content-Type', "application/rss+xml");
```

but get an error.

I added this part `->header('Content-Type', "application/rss+xml")`

Original was: `return View::make('rss', $data);`

Comment: Giorgi, would be awesome if you could accept Exprator's answer! :) Just click the accept button next to his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
return Response::view('hello')->header('Content-Type', $type);
```

Or try this:

```
$contents = View::make('embedded')->with('foo', $foo);
$response = Response::make($contents, $statusCode);
$response->header('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
return $response;
```

Comment: Hello @Exprator thank you for response.

I get his error:
Call to undefined function response()